# Problem using promise and await on a Vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm running a function in mounted() to grab files from my Dropbox account using a promise. On success of this promise, I loop all files and run another promise function to grab additional info of each files and add it to object.

```
data () {
    return {
        results: [],
        dropbox: [],
    }
},
mounted() {
    dropbox.filesListFolder({path: '/wallpapers'}).then(this.successHandler)
    this.dropbox = dropbox
},
methods: {
    successHandler (response) {
        const files = response.entries;
        async function processArray(files) {
            for (const item of files) {
                item['meta'] = await this.getFileInfo(item.id);
            }
        }
        processArray(files);
        this.results = files;
    }
    getFileInfo (id) {
        this.dropbox.filesGetMetadata({
            path: id,
        })
        .then(this.successFileInfo)
    },
    successFileInfo (response) {
        return response; 
    }
}
```

But this return an error:

> Cannot read property 'getFileInfo' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scope-problem - wrong `this`:

```
    let vm = this;
    async function processArray(files) {
        for (const item of files) {
            item['meta'] = await vm.getFileInfo(item.id);
        }
    }
```

---

Or you can do:

```
processArray.bind(this)(files);
```

---

UPD (from comments):

You forgot return in `getFileInfo`-method

```
getFileInfo (id) {
    return this.dropbox.filesGetMetadata({
        path: id,
    })
    .then(this.successFileInfo)
}
```

Comment: Both suggestions fixed the error. But now the `successFileInfo` method return `undefined` instead `response` object. I confirm that `console.log(response);` inside the method return the object.

Comment: `getFileInfo`-method returns nothing ;)

Comment: Return an object from `successFileInfo()`. `await vm.getFileInfo(item.id)` is not waiting for this function return?

Comment: Fixed! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `item['meta'] = await this.getFileInfo(item.id);`, `this` refers to the scope of the `processArray` function and not the vue component.

If I'm not mistaken, you should just be able to do:

```
async successHandler (response) {
    const files = response.entries;
    for (const item of files) {
        item['meta'] = await this.getFileInfo(item.id);
    }
    processArray(files);
    this.results = files;
}
```